# Asp.Net WebApi 2: Add role claim to WindowsIdentity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, windows-identity

I want to add a role claim to an already authenticated windows user. My naive first approach was to add the role claim inside of a custom owin middleware which runs before WebApi. Like this:

```
public class IdentityMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public IdentityMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
    }

    public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        var user = context.Request.User as WindowsPrincipal;
        var identity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));

        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

However when providing the Authorize attribute in the controller like this.

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public string Get()
    {
        return User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

..I will get a **401**.

I noticed that the issuer of the new claim is "Local Authority" instead of "AD Authority" could this be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this for your authorize attribute:

```
[Authorize(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")]
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is no such Constructor for the AuthorizeAttribute in System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0

Comment: If your issue isn't fixed yet, you can write a custom authorize attribute by inheriting from System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute and check your claims 'manually'

Comment: Thats exactly what I was trying to avoid but ended up doing anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var сlaimsIdentity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
сlaimsIdentity?.AddClaim(new Claim(сlaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType, "Admin"));
if (user.IsInRole("Admin")) ... // always true
```